# How do I indent a line in an enumeration environment?

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

This is what my document looks like so far:
[image]

What I want is to have an indent at the line "I" is a subset of I'...". How do I do that within an item of an enumeration?

This is my code:

```
\begin{enumerate}    
  \item \leavevmode

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $I^\prime$ is the domain of $f^\prime$. $I^{\prime\prime}$ is the domain of $f^{\prime\prime}$. Partial function $f^\prime$ extends partial function $f^{\prime\prime}$ if: \\ $I^{\prime\prime}$ is a subset of $I^\prime$ where for all $x \in I^{\prime\prime}$, $f^{\prime\prime}(x) = f^\prime(x)$.
    \item sub list 2
    \item sub list 3

  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: As a one-off thing? At the start of your second change you second `\begin{enumerate}` to `\begin{enumerate}\parindent15pt` and change your manual break `\\ ` to `\par` (or with the usual blank line).

Comment: Note that if you want this indentation to be a 'global' setting, what I suggested above is not the best way.

Comment: please, give us a MWE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is managed by the parameter `\listparindent`The simplest is to use the key `listparindent`of `enumitem`.  Note you don't have to use `\prime` and `^{\prime\prime}` to denote the first and second derivatives: `'` and `''` work perfectly well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \leavevmode
  \begin{enumerate}[listparindent=1em]
  \item $I'$ is the domain of $f'$. $I''$ is the domain of $f''$. Partial function $f'$ extends partial function $f'' $ if:

     $I''$ is a subset of $I'$ where for all $x \in I''$, $f''(x) = f'(x)$.

  \item sub list 2

  \item sub list 3
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this but I don't think it is the best way ; maybe you could do an other itemize environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}    
\item \leavevmode

  \begin{enumerate}
  \item $I^\prime$ is the domain of $f^\prime$. $I^{\prime\prime}$ is the domain of $f^{\prime\prime}$. Partial function $f^\prime$ extends partial function $f^{\prime\prime}$ if: \\
    \hspace*{1cm} $I^{\prime\prime}$ is a subset of $I^\prime$ where for all $x \in I^{\prime\prime}$, $f^{\prime\prime}(x) = f^\prime(x)$.
  \item sub list 2
  \item sub list 3

  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]